# 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double' error when using ggpredict() with "gam" object

Tags: r, debugging, gam, mgcv, ggeffects

I have generated a Generalized Additive Mixed Model (GAMM) with `mcgv::gamm()` and have no problem using `ggeffects::ggpredict()` to make estimated marginal means predictions with the model and then plot them with `ggplot2()`. However, I am running into an error when I save my workspace, close it, and re-open it. When I do this and try to plot the same model with `ggeffects::ggpredict()` I receive the error message:

`Error in is.constant(y) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

This must surely be a glitch since the plotting works fine until I exit the session. I don't want to re-run my models every time that I want to plot them, because they are built using large datasets, smoothing functions, and random effects, and are very time-consuming (many hours) to run. Does anyone know of a work-around?

Thank you very much.

**Edit: 05 Dec 2023 (in response to comments by Miff and Gavin Simpson)**

Thank you both for your responses.

Both packages---i.e. `ggeffects` and `mgcv`---were loaded. As Gavin noted, the object generated by `mgcv::gamm()` gives two options: `$lme` or `$gam`. `class(model)` gives the class as `"gamm" "list"`. For some reason, running `ggeffects::ggpredict(model)` works fine during the session in which you created the `gamm` object, but gives the error message if you save, exit, and restart R. However, specifying `ggeffects::ggpredict(model$gam)` seems to be resolving the issue (n.b. `ggeffects::ggpredict(model$lme)` gives the error message `Error in eval(x$call$random) : object 'rand' not found`, presumably because there is a random effect in my model that it can't handle).

I will update further if any other issues.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's hard to be sure what's going on here, but it's likely that you need to load one of the packages in the new session that you used in the session that created the object, my guess is you need `library(mgcv)`

Comment: @Miff Thank you, I have responded by editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

The models returned by `gamm()` consist of a list with a `$lme` component and a `$gam` component, each representing the two views of the model. Try

```r
ggpredict(my_model$gam)
```

or

```r
ggpredict(my_model$lme)
```

depending on how you want to do predictions and how you want to handle predictions with the random effects.

Comment: Thank you, I have responded by editing the question.

Comment: Are you reloading both packages when you restart?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when `ggpredict()` is called, the correct slot (`$gam`) is automatically selected:

```r
  # for gamm/gamm4 objects, we have a list with two items, mer and gam
  # extract just the gam-part then
  if (is.gamm(model) || is.gamm4(model)) {
    model <- model$gam
  }
```

(https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects/blob/master/R/ggpredict.R#L638C1-L643C1)

Can you post your `sessionInfo()` for both situations (where it works, and when you get an error)?